# Extract a Folder from Duplicity Archive

Tags: restore, duplicity

Using the duplicity command, I need to specify the following:

- a specific folder to restore
- indicate time and date from which to restore
- indicate the destination to restore to

How can I specify these 3 things using the duplicity command?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's correct, even if it tells "--file-to-restore", you can enter any file or folder path (without the "/" sign at the beginning of it, for example "temp/logs") at "foldername" and any "destination folder" (with the "/"sign at the beginning of it, for example "/temp/logs") to the command.

Sample: I want to restore my /temp/logs which is backed-up 3 days ago into the same folder:

```
duplicity -t 3D --file-to-restore temp/logs file:///backup/location /temp/logs
```

Sample2: I want to restore my file /temp/logs/app-error.log which is backed-up 3 days ago into the same folder:

```
duplicity -t 3D --file-to-restore temp/logs/app-error.log file:///backup/location /temp/logs/app-error.log
```

Note that you have to give a full destination path for the file.

Sample3: My backup stays at an ftp server=my.ftp.server with user=root at the location=my_backup, the same scenario with #1:

```
duplicity -t 3D --file-to-restore temp/logs sftp://root@my.ftp.server/my_backup /temp/logs
```

Comment: Actually, when using the parameter `--file-to-restore` in duplicity 0.8.12 and specifying a file or directory to restore, I had to use the *absolute* path instead of a relative one. This is opposed to that the documentation states. Otherwise I always got an error message that the indicated file/path cannot be found in the backup.

Answer (score 10):

```
duplicity -t 3D --file-to-restore <foldername> file:///backup/location <destination folder>
```

Duplicity enters restore mode because the URL comes before the local directory.

`-t 3D` 3 days ago

If you want to check more information, here are useful links depending on the version:

- http://duplicity.nongnu.org/vers7/duplicity.1.html
- http://duplicity.nongnu.org/docs.html
- https://duplicity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/