# How can I restore a folder backed up on my old computer running Ubuntu to my new one?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

To my surprise and delight I was able to do this. I figured I should document it somewhere. It synthesizes a couple other answers I found to guide me but focuses on a case that I haven't seen addressed directly.

This is my situation: a couple years ago I replaced my home computer. My old computer was running Ubuntu 14. My new one is running Ubuntu 16. On the old computer, I was making regular backups to an external drive using backups/deja-dup/duplicity.

A couple days ago, the hard drive on my old computer (Ubuntu 14 one) died. I had copied over most the important stuff to my new computer (Ubuntu 16). However, there was a projects folder that still had some older projects that I hadn't gotten around to copying over. So I wanted to see if I could restore this folder from the backups on the external drive.

This is the path of the folder from my old computer I wanted to restore:

- `/home/klenwell/projects`

This is the path of the folder on my external drive where the backups were being saved (after plugging external drive into new computer):

- `/media/klenwell/my-external-drive/u2014`

I wanted to restore it to a folder at this path on my new computer:

- `/tmp/restored/u2014/projects`

Answer (score 0):

First, a quick refresher from question above on the key paths I'll be working with here:

- Folder from old dead computer I want to restore: `/home/klenwell/projects`
- Folder of old computer backups on external drive (when plugged into new computer): `/media/klenwell/my-external-drive/u2014`
- Folder on new computer where I want restore folder: `/tmp/restored/u2014/projects`

#### Command Line

From command line, here at the command I ran to restore the backup. See the next section for a step-by-step guide with explanation:

```
# backup new project directory (to be safe)
mkdir /tmp/new-projects-backup
cp -R ~/projects /tmp/new-projects-backup

# review list of backed up paths from old computer
sudo duplicity list-current-files file:///media/klenwell/my-external-drive/u2014 > /tmp/u2014-backup-list.txt
less /tmp/u2014-backup-list.txt

# make destination folder for restored directory
mkdir /tmp/restored/u2014/projects

# restore backup
sudo duplicity restore \
  --file-to-restore home/klenwell/projects  \
  file:///media/klenwell/my-external-drive/u2014 \
  /tmp/restored/u2014/projects

# confirm folder has been restored
ls -al /tmp/restored/u2014/projects
```

#### Step-By-Step Guide

Here's a break down of the commands below with explanations for each command:

1. Plug in external drive to new computer and confirm it's accessible:

   ```
   ls -al /media/klenwell
   ```

   Notes:

   - In reality, the mounted external drive's directory name a random string like `ksdfd987s-0sll1332-skd09233`.
   - To simplify this guide, I will assume it was named `my-external-drive` and backups were in folder `u2014`.
2. Confirm I can see backed up files from older computer:

   ```
   sudo duplicity list-current-files file:///media/klenwell/my-external-drive/u2014 > /tmp/u2014-backup-list.txt
   less /tmp/u2014-backup-list.txt
   ```

   Notes:

   - I needed to use `sudo` to deal with this import error: https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/duplicity-talk/2013-10/msg00002.html
   - I needed to know the password I used to encrypt backups on my old computer meaning I entered 2 password: my sudo password and my backups password.
   - Note the `file://` prefix for my backups folder path.
   - It took a few minutes to generate the output file.
3. Back up `/home/klenwell/projects` on my new computer just to be safe in case duplicity tries to restore the backup folder to same path for some strange reason:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/new-projects-backup
   cp -R ~/projects /tmp/new-projects-backup
   ```
4. Here's where the magic happens (it was a somewhat large directory so it took a few minutes in my case):

   ```
   sudo duplicity restore \
     --file-to-restore home/klenwell/projects  \
     file:///media/klenwell/my-external-drive/u2014 \
     /tmp/restored/u2014/projects
   ```
5. And to confirm all went well, I should now see my old project directory restored:

   ```
   ls -al /tmp/restored/u2014/projects
   ```

#### References

- https://askubuntu.com/a/332914
- [Extract a Folder from Duplicity Archive](https://askubuntu.com/q/520152/46766)
- https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/duplicity-talk/2013-10/msg00002.html